Disabling Render causes Rigid Body object to recalc during render
I have a baked RB simulation that looks fine when played in the View.

Instead of using a clear, see-through material on the Cube Passive RB where I have sphere Actives bouncing off, I decided to disable rendering on this (enabling Holdout would cause some unwanted gray-scale in the result).

However, the render-animation result seems to ignore the Baked RB simulation and re-calculated with a very jittery result:

To me this enters the level of bug as to its unexpected side effects.   Other than kludging up a see-through material for the cube, am I missing a more expected, straight-forward way to use the RBW cache during rendering?
My example: 
